# How to get number of instagram posts in specific location and with specific tag

Tags: javascript, typescript, instagram-api

I looked at the Instagram API (maybe not efficiently, who knows?) but I didn't find a way to use a kind of REST API allowing the search of the number of posts in a specific location and with a specific hashtag.
I don't care about the pictures themself, my goal is, with a kind of filter like: 'specific location : FRANCE' & 'hashtag : Beach', to get a list of public posts (here, all the posts in France where the hashtag Beach has been used) with :
- accurated location (city or lat/lon)
- tags
- timestamp

In the Instagram API the technologies allowed are Ruby, Python and PHP but I juste want a way to use it though a request in JS/TS and put a clustering of the result on a map !
Not sure if it's possible but in the app it is (with hashtags only) so if you've got a clue, please, give it to me ! =)

Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instagram has deprecated their old REST API [source](https://www.business2community.com/brandviews/upwork/how-the-new-instagram-graph-api-is-changing-social-media-marketing-02112428) and replaced it with a Facebook-like [Graph API](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-api). In that Graph API, you can search for hashtags but you are limited to [30 unique hashtags in a rolling 7 day period](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-api/reference/hashtag). And even with the hashtag search, you are unable to get location data about the results. You might have luck looking at the results and searching for specific text strings, but there is no longer anything like what you are looking for in the Instagram API, largely due to privacy concerns.

Comment: Arf... That's what I feared... And do you know a kind a free online source of geolocated data that I could use for my goal ? I read something about Foursquare but I'm not sure that it could fit with my needs...